# Fetch one and one row in Python(Tree function)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to convert this PHP code into Python. It is simply returning options in tree hierarchy.

```php
function getAllSectors(&$output = null, $parent_id = 0, $indent = null){

        $statement = $this->connect()->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM sectors WHERE parent_id =:parent_id ORDER BY parent_id, sort_order");

        $statement->execute(array(
            'parent_id'     => $parent_id
        ));

        // show the sectors one by one
        while($row = $statement->fetch()){
            $output .= '<option value=' . $row['id'] . '>' . $indent . $row['name'] . "</option>";
            if($row['id'] != $parent_id){
                // In case the current sectors's id is different than $parent_id
                // I call the function again with new parameters(so it is recursive)
                $this->getAllSectors($output, $row['id'], $indent . "&nbsp;&nbsp;");
            }
        }
        // return the list of sectors(call out is in index.php)
        return $output;
    }
```

And I tried like this in Python:

```
class Category(BaseModel, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'category'
    __forbidden_fields__ = BaseModel.__forbidden_fields__
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('category.id'))
    sort_order = Column(Integer)
    users = relationship("UserCategory", back_populates="category")

def get_all_categories(cls, output = '', parent_id = 0, indent = ''):
    categories = cls.db.query(Category).filter(Category.is_deleted == 0).all()
    output = "<option value='{id}'>'{indent}''{name'}' </option>"
    for c in categories:
        if c.id != parent_id:
            cls.get_all_categories(output, c.id, indent)
    print(output)
```

I am using Python, SQLAlchemy, Tornado, Backbone.

But I do not know how to pass by reference the `output` parameter. I aso think that the Python version has infinity loop, am I correct? Can anybody give me suggestions?

Comment: Where is your filter on `parent_id`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters about what `parent_id` filter you are talking about?

Comment: Your query returns *all undeleted Category objects*. The PHP code only produces those that match the parent id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper translation of your PHP code would be:

```
def get_all_categories(cls, parent_id=None, indent=''):
    output = []
    categories = cls.db.query(Category).filter(~Category.is_deleted, Category.parent_id==parent_id)
    for cat in categories.order_by(Category.sort_order):
        output.append(
            '<option value={cat.id}>{indent}{cat.name}</option>\n'.format(
                cat=cat, indent=indent))
        if cat.id != parent_id:
            output.append(cls.get_all_categories(cat.id, indent + '&nbsp;&nbsp;'))
    return ''.join(output)
```

There is no need to pass `output` in to the recursive call, just collect the output and add it to the current output being built. I used a list to avoid repeated string concatenation (which would give you quadratic performance, rather than linear).

You were also missing the `ORDER BY` clause; there is no need to order by `parent_id` when you are at the same time filtering on the parent id (they are all going to be the same), so you only need to sort on the `sort_order` column.

I'm assuming this is SQLAlchemy; you can use `~` to state a `WHERE NOT <column>` clause.

You should also consider separating the *presentation* from retrieving the categories as a tree. You can then move to a generator approach and avoid the memory footprint of having to hold the whole tree in memory (although SQLAlchemy will cache most anyway):

```
def get_all_categories(cls, parent_id=None):
    categories = cls.db.query(Category).filter(~Category.is_deleted, Category.parent_id==parent_id)
    for cat in categories.order_by(Category.sort_order):
        yield {category: cat, children: cls.get_all_categories(cat.id)}
```

and then use the templating engine to render the `children` elements recursively.

For a demo, lets first build some categories in an in-memory database; this uses a simplified version of your model; the tree is as follows:

- Foo

  - Spam
  - Ham
- Bar

  - Gone (marked as deleted)

The setup code:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>> engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
>>> from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
>>> Base = declarative_base()
>>> from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Boolean, ForeignKey
>>> class Category(Base):
...     __tablename__ = 'category'
...     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
...     name = Column(String(50))
...     parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('category.id'))
...     sort_order = Column(Integer)
...     is_deleted = Column(Boolean, default=False)
...
>>> Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
>>> from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
>>> session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
>>> foo = Category(name='Foo', sort_order=1)
>>> bar = Category(name='Bar', sort_order=2)
>>> session.add_all([foo, bar])
>>> session.flush()
>>> spam = Category(name='Spam', parent_id=foo.id, sort_order=1)
>>> ham = Category(name='Ham', parent_id=foo.id, sort_order=2)
>>> gone = Category(name='Gone', parent_id=bar.id, sort_order=1, is_deleted=True)
>>> session.add_all([spam, ham, gone])
>>> session.commit()
```

and then using a dummy class to bind the class method to, the output can be produced:

```
>>> class Demo:
...     db = session
...     @classmethod
...     def get_all_categories(cls, parent_id=None, indent=''):
...         output = []
...         categories = cls.db.query(Category).filter(~Category.is_deleted, Category.parent_id==parent_id)
...         for cat in categories.order_by(Category.sort_order):
...             output.append(
...                 '<option value={cat.id}>{indent}{cat.name}</option>\n'.format(
...                     cat=cat, indent=indent))
...             if cat.id != parent_id:
...                 output.append(cls.get_all_categories(cat.id, indent + '&nbsp;&nbsp;'))
...         return ''.join(output)
...
>>> print(Demo.get_all_categories())
<option value=1>Foo</option>
<option value=3>&nbsp;&nbsp;Spam</option>
<option value=4>&nbsp;&nbsp;Ham</option>
<option value=2>Bar</option>
```

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp the top-level categories; do they have patent_id set to 0 or NULL?

Comment: It is set to NULL by default

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp: sorry, no, it wasn't, I have corrected that, as well as defaulting `parent_id` to `NULL`. It would help if you added a minimal model definition to your question though.

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp: that was a mistake transcribing the PHP code; corrected now.

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp: yup, now that I have a sample mapping I'm building a demo. Correction applied.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explenation. I got it working :)